# How to use SLDS Icon in Visualforce Component

Tags: visualforce-component, slds

I have tried to used below code in Visualforce Component

```
<img class="slds-checklrt" src="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS,'assets/icons/utility/check_60.png')}" style="width:20px"/>
```

but not getting much output as per requirement.

Any solution for this?

Comment: can you let us know specifically what is not getting with $Asset

Comment: we need to check icon but it display none image icon.

Comment: I have put this code in VF page and go to inspect element find "/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/utility/check_60.png" this src while "/_slds/icons/utility/check_60.png" this src in VF Component.

Answer (score 3):

We can't use lightning icon direct from **"Asset.SLDS"**.
Please use Lightning Assets path:

```
<img src="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/utility/check_60.png"/>
```

or you can use SVG:

```
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="description of icon when needed"> 
    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon">
        <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account')}"></use>
    </svg>
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Icon Assistive Text</span>
</span>
```

Plese follow below link if needed:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_icons.htm